# Calculate a n-byn matrix using values in 2 vectors (lengths of n) in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to calculate a n-by-n matrix in R using the values from 2 n vectors.
For example, let's say I have the following vectors.

formula f(x,y)=x+y

```
x<-c(1,2,3)
y<-c(8,9,10)
```

z should be a 3-by-3 matrix where z[0][0] is f(0,0) z[0][1] is f(0,1). IS there any way to perform such a calculation in R?

Comment: In R, the index starts from `1`

Answer (score 2):

You can try `outer`

```
outer(x, y, FUN= f)
```

where

```
f <- function(x,y)  x+y
```